# Operational amplifier input voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, input-offset-voltage

I give the same voltage to opamp inputs (AD 744) but the output depends on the Vcc value.

- Vcc voltage is 8.00V, the output voltage is going to 7.36.
- Vcc voltage is 6.00V, the output voltage is going to 5.78.

Please explain to me what happens.

Comment: You have not included a schematic of your circuit.  Hit the edit button at the bottom of your question and use the built in schematic editor to add one.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have the output railed and you are just seeing the highest voltage that poor op-amp can manage with the supply voltage you are giving it.

[image]

If you are literally putting the same voltage on both inputs with no feedback it will almost surely either be railed at the positive or negative limits. That's because of the [high gain](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD744.pdf) (400,000 typical) and typical +/-250uV offset, which means the opamp should be putting out +/-100V typically.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't know how op amps operate and what they're for. The op amp takes the difference between inputs, multiplies is by 100,000 or even a million and produces in on the output (in your circuit configuration - no feedback loops). Now, it would be hard to output some million volts, because op amp has its power rails, which limit its output voltage. In real life many op amps don't even produce output entirely from the bottom voltage to the top voltage.

So basically due to imperfection and tiny input mismatch your inputs are NOT exactly on the same level - purely for production imperfection reasons at least. So you send into inputs slightly different voltages, your op amp tries to output many kilovolts (which it obviously can't, being powered from 8V), so it tries to output maximum 8V ("saturates"), but again it's not perfect, so it outputs just as much as it can (7.36V). There are "rail-to-rail" op amps, that can output voltages very close to power rails (down to microvolts). They're not really expensive anymore, and there's plenty of choice.

As for what exactly op amps are and how to use them, check out the Youtube video of EEVBlog - op amps. I think Dave explains it very clearly. What they are, how they work, how to use them. With examples and all. That's how I learned it back in the days)

Comment: Nice explanation... I would also highly recommend Bob DuHamel's RSD Academy...

Answer (score 0):

The operational amplifier is like a hypersensitive scale that you can never balance. If you apply two voltages to its inputs and change one of them, the output voltage will become zero only for the brief moment of their equality; the op-amp acts as a *comparator*.

If you want to maintain this balance, you must have the op-amp itself maintain the one voltage equal to the other. This is called *negative feedback*.